# What happens when Google Play beta reaches it's limit

Tags: android, google-play

I'm using open beta for my app in Google play.
In case I'm setting a maximum number of testers, what would happen when a user will try to join the beta after its limit has been reached?

Answer (score 0):

New users won't be able to join the beta after the limit is reached.

Comment: Will new users see the Google play testing page saying that the beta reached to it's limit?

Answer (score 0):

Just stop beta distribution, check this [Hangout](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/UquKud2EXts) to learn more information:

Comment: It's still don't answer my question, it's not specific enough.
When the beta reaches its limit, will user that navigating to the Opt-in URL will see an error message?

Comment: No, just cant click download.